# How to change the default browser to another browser in the lite server, when I working with truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle, server-side, configuration, truffle-config

I am a beginner in etherium blockchain-related development. I am trying to develop a simple app using truffle, ganache and metamask. I want to change my default browser to chrome when I run the lite server. How I can do it? I am using vscode to code those stuff. I put my truffle and browser configurations below,

**browser config file**

```
{
    "server":{
        "baseDir":[
            "./src",
            "./build/contracts"
        ],
        "routes":{
            "/vendor":"./node_modules"
        },
         "browser": "Google Chrome"
    }
    
}
```

**truffle-config file**

```
    module.exports={
  networks:{
    development:{
      host:"127.0.0.1",
      port:7545,
      network_id:"*" //match any network id
    }
  },
  solc:{
    optimizer:{
      enabled:true,
      runs:200
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a configuration in your **vscode**, then add this configuration to your `truffle.js` or `truffle.config.js`, it should be something like that:

```js
networks: {
  development: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 8080,
    network_id: "*" // match any network
  },
  mynetwork: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 8545,
    network_id: "*" // match any network
  },
}
```

> You may need to add this lines in your vscode `settings.json`.
>
> > A **value 0** (zero) is used for a random port, so any **other number** is for a fixed port number.

```json
{
    "liveServer.settings.multiRootWorkspaceName": "",
    "liveServer.settings.port": 0
}
```